# What is the maximum possible value of $k$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> What is the maximum possible value of $k$ for which $2013$ can be written as a sum of $k$ consecutive positive integers?

I tried to write $2013$ as a sum of AP with common difference $1$ then factorize one side of the expression, I don't know if it's true or not, any help will be appraciated.

Comment: $2013 = 3\times11\times61$. If the number of terms is odd, what do we know about the relationship between the number of terms and their average value?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $a$ be the first integer in the $n$ consecutive integers. We get $$n(2a+n-1)=4026=2 \cdot  3\cdot  11\cdot  61$$

Now as $$2a+n-1>n \Rightarrow  4026> n^{2}$$

the maximum value of $n$ occurs at $n = 61.$

and we're done

Comment: It's a little hard to see why you made the second part of your argument to conclude that $n = 61$. I assume you were insinuating that due to the factorization, the smallest possible value $n > 61$ would be $n = 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 11 = 66$ and $66^2 > 4026?$? It might help to point that out. I didn't realize $66^2 > 4026$ until I guessed that was what you were getting at and I checked it on a calculator.